# SVG animation with timing function not working in Firefox

Tags: animation, svg

Works on Chrome/Safari.

```
<svg height="50" viewBox="0 0 16 10">
  <rect class="background" width="16" height="10"></rect>
  <rect class="vertical" width="2" x="5">
    <animate calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" attributeName="height" from="0" to="10" dur="0.5s" begin="1.3s" fill="freeze"></animate>
  </rect>
  <rect class="horizontal" height="2" y="4">
     <animate calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" attributeName="width" from="0" to="16" dur="0.5s" begin="0.8s" fill="freeze"></animate>
  </rect>
</svg>
```

If I remove the `calcMode`, `keyTimes` and `keySplines` attributes it starts working in Firefox too.

Comment: Firefox is correct not to animate, you should raise this bug on the webkit and Chrome bugtrackers.

Answer (score 1):

In SVG1.1 (I don't know about SVG2),

- You must have a `values` attribute along the [`keyTimes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/keyTimes) attribute.
- [specs on `keySplines`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#KeySplinesAttribute) say that :

  > there must be one fewer sets of control points than there are
  >   ‘keyTimes’.

FF is then correct here, and others should raise an error and not animate.

```html
<svg height="50" viewBox="0 0 16 10">

  <rect class="vertical" width="2" x="5">
    <animate calcMode="spline" values="0;2.2;3.3;5.5;6.6;8.8;10" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1;  0.1 0.8 0.2 1;" attributeName="height" from="0" to="10" dur="0.5s" begin="1.3s" fill="freeze"></animate>
  </rect>
  <rect class="horizontal" height="2" y="4">
     <animate calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1" values="0;2.2;3.3;5.5;6.6;8.8;10" keySplines="0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1; 0.1 0.8 0.2 1" attributeName="width" from="0" to="16" dur="0.5s" begin="0.8s" fill="freeze"></animate>
  </rect>
</svg>
```